# Create a function returns array in vimscript

Tags: vim

I have a function in my vimrc returns VimAle errors and warnings status.

```
function! LinterStatus() abort
  let l:counts = ale#statusline#Count(bufnr(''))

  let l:all_errors = l:counts.error + l:counts.style_error
  let l:all_non_errors = l:counts.total - l:all_errors

  return l:counts.total == 0 ? 'OK' : printf(
        \   '%d W, %d E',
        \   all_non_errors,
        \   all_errors
        \)
endfunction
```

I use this function in my `statusline` to display count of warnings and errors if any.

I would like to modify this function so that it can return three values in array(example [is_clean, errors, warnings]). I wanna use independent values in `statusline` so that i can change text colour, background etc.

Comment: Hi there. Please try to formulate a clear distinct question. What exactly is your problem, what have you tried?

Comment: It's `return [l:counts.total == 0, l:all_errors, l:all_non_errors]`, isn't it?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo what i am trying is already mention in question. My problem is i want to get array with warnings, errors, and total count in array instead of string like in function mentioned above.

I am using this string currently in my statusline. However if'll get array i can use it with more flexibility, like in different positions with different colours etc.

Comment: Yeah but what is your problem with it? do you don't know how to return an array? how to build an array? how to access a returned array? I honestly don't get it

Comment: @phd Thanks :)

`return [l:counts.total, l:all_errors, l:all_non_errors]` That's what i am looking for

I tried it before as well, but might be because of other issues in my vimrc it was not working. However it's working now, Thanks :)

Comment: @phd can you post it as answer so that i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just

```
return [l:counts.total, l:all_errors, l:all_non_errors]
```

Nothing fancy.